# MySQL IF Condition in a Calculated Field

Tags: sql, mysql, if-statement

I am trying to create a calculated field where if two values happen to be the same, the value doubles. I am coding this condition in the variable MY.  I am new to SQL, so I apologize.

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT EXPERT_SCORE*MY
IF(CONSUMER_EXPERT_SCORE_ID= CONSUMER_EXPERT_ID, 1, -1) AS MY 
FROM consumer_expert_score
WHERE CONSUMER_EXPERT_SCORE_ID=2 OR 1;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please post some sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want CASE WHEN, and the IN ( ) clause.

Unfortunately I could not rewrite your query completely because your conditional is a tautology, it will always return 1.  Maybe you meant something else?  Anyway, I changed it up a bit to what I think you might have meant:

```
SELECT ....
  case when consumer_expert_id = 1 then 1 else -1 end as my
  from consumer_expert_score
 where consumer_expert_score_id IN (2,1)
```

Comment: sorry, I meant to add a different column

Comment: If you edit your original post I can mod the query as well, might be helpful for anybody else who examines this question

Comment: ...the part I don't get is that you are trying to double something.  Now that we have the CASE WHEN and IN () figured out, we can probably figure that out next

Comment: My conditional needs the case to changed based on if two values are the same.

Comment: I am just trying to master how to do this so I can implement it on a more complicated equation

Comment: I just want to clarify what the ... is supposed to be.

Comment: I guess @quassosnoi's comment is the way to go them, can you provide a few rows of sample data and the desired output?