# MySQL distance calculations

Tags: mysql, having

I am using the following code to fetch my database for events within specific distances of an inputted latitude and longitude:

```
SELECT *,
    (3959 * acos(
        cos( radians( $latitude ) )
        * cos( radians( event_latitude ) )
        * cos( radians( event_longitude ) - radians( $longitude ) )
        + sin( radians( $latitude ) )
        * sin( radians( event_latitude ) )
    )) AS distance
FROM events
HAVING distance < $distance
```

This works great. However, some of my events don't have a latitude or longitude at all (they dont have physical locations). So for them, the `event_latitude` and `event_longitude` both equal `0`.

Is there a way to fetch by `HAVING distance` or `event_latitude = 0`? So that I can get a result that has events within a specific distance AND events which dont have a latitude or longitude at all?

If I put an evaluation check for 0 in a `WHERE` clause, it will still fail the `HAVING` check. And I can't put the evaluation in the `HAVING` clause because I get an unknown column error.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Add `or sum(event_latitude = 0) > 0` to the end

Comment: Are the event_lat/long fields NULL when events have no physical locations? Could you post your DB structure? What is the default values of those lat long fields?

Comment: They are not null, they are 0.

Comment: if the fields are zero, the above query does not return those results? sin(0) is 0 and cos(0) is 1 and with all the multiplications, it should come out as just 0. does it error out or something?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at conditional select statements [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html) You can write something like if the field is 0 then fetch it as is and if it is not, then do the calculation.

Comment: That wouldn't give the results I want. That would give me only events which have latitudes and longitudes. I want events within a distance OR events where latitudes and longitudes are zero.

Comment: You can look at this question as a simple example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809155/mysql-if-condition-in-a-calculated-field

Comment: I dont get how that simple example works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something; does this not work?

```
SELECT *,
    (3959 * acos(
        cos( radians( $latitude ) )
        * cos( radians( event_latitude ) )
        * cos( radians( event_longitude ) - radians( $longitude ) )
        + sin( radians( $latitude ) )
        * sin( radians( event_latitude ) )
    )) AS distance
FROM events
HAVING distance < :distance OR (event_latitude = 0 AND event_longitude = 0)
```

(note, I swapped your $distance for a :distance since it should be a parameter probably).

Comment: No, it does not. The following gives an Unknown Column error for event_latitude and event_longitude.

Comment: that's odd, because you're using those columns in your calculation for distance, and returning them with `SELECT *` - can you confirm you haven't removed the `*` from your `SELECT` query when you test this?

Comment: As an aside, is there a reason you're using a `HAVING` clause instead of a `WHERE` clause?